# I typed in one order but they appeared in reverse order. Please help

Tags: tables, floats, equations

[image]

There are two parts to this code. First is the figures and calculations after. (Indicated by the two comments). But when I run them they appeared in the reverse order.

```
\subsection*{Figures}
\begin{center}       
%should appear first
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{../figures/Ptime.jpg}
        \caption{Pressure vs Step}
        \vspace{4ex}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{../figures/temptime.jpg}
        \caption{Temperature vs Step}
        \vspace{4ex}
        \end{subfigure} 
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{../figures/KEtime.jpg}
        \caption{Kinetic Energy vs Step}
        \end{subfigure} 
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{../figures/PEtime.jpg}
        \caption{Potential Energy vs Step}
        \end{subfigure}
    \caption{}
    \end{figure}
    \end{center}
    %should appear next
    \textit{Calculation of Self Diffusion Coefficient}
    \begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
    \text{slope} & = 0.0021 \\
    \text{Self Diffusion Coeff} & =\frac{1}{6}\times \text{(Slope of MSD at long time)}\\
    & = \frac{1}{6} \times \text{0.0021}\\
    & = \SI{3.5e-4} {\text{LJ units}}
    \end{split}
    \end{equation*}
    \text{Considering the LJ liquid to be liquid Ar, we have $\sigma = 0.34 \textit{ nm}$, $\frac{\epsilon}{k_B}=120 \textit{ K}$. }\\
    \text{$\therefore \frac{{(L^*)}^2}{t^*}=\frac{{L^2}/{\sigma^2}}{t\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{m\sigma^2}}}\implies \frac{L^2}{t}= (\sigma^3\sqrt{m/\epsilon}) \frac{(L^*)^2}{t^*} \implies \frac{L^2}{\epsilon}=\num{2.49e-31}\frac{(L^*)^2}{t^*}$}
    \linebreak
    \begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
    \text{Diffusion Coefficient in SI Units} &= \num{3.5e-4}\times \SI{2.489e-31}{\meter^2 /\second}\\
    &=\SI{8.7e-34}{\meter^2 /\second}
    \end{split}
    \end{equation*}
```

Comment: Search for "Figures position". It can be a pain in the neck. The `[ht]` after `\begin{figure}` is what you need to experiment with. The `h` is a soft "here" the `t` is a "top" (as in top of the page). If it is ok, try changing the `t` to a `b` (bottom), or try changing the `h` to a `H` (a "hard" here).

Comment: Putting a figure inside center dies not make sense as the figure floats I would start by setting the float placement to `[htp] ` and work from there. The H has its uses but should not be used in a normal document

Comment: did the answer below meet your requirement?

Comment: The short answer is that the `{figure}` environment is allowed to *float* to where TeX thinks is best.  If you don't want that, you don't need to use the `{figure}` environment.  A longer answer would be https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/107497 and everything that links to it.

Answer (score -2):

Works correctly once the text above the second eqn is shortened to just one text word `considering` --probably some error in the eqn  --other than that lines up correctly

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb,booktabs}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Figures}
\begin{center}       
%should appear first
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Pressure vs Step}
        \vspace{4ex}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Temperature vs Step}
        \vspace{4ex}
        \end{subfigure} 
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Kinetic Energy vs Step}
        \end{subfigure} 
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Potential Energy vs Step}
        \end{subfigure}
    \caption{}
    \end{figure}
    \end{center}
    %should appear next
    \textit{Calculation of Self Diffusion Coefficient}
    \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
TCU & = \frac{\text{purchasing cost} + \text{setup cost} + \text{holding cost}}{time} \\
    & = \frac{cy+K+h\frac{y}{2}t_0}{t_0}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
    \text{Considering the LJ liquid to be liquid Ar, we have $\sigma = 0.34 \textit{ nm}$, $\frac{\epsilon}{k_B}=120 \textit{ K}$. }\\
    \text{$\therefore \frac{{(L^*)}^2}{t^*}=\frac{{L^2}/{\sigma^2}}{t\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{m\sigma^2}}}\implies \frac{L^2}{t}= (\sigma^3\sqrt{m/\epsilon}) \frac{(L^*)^2}{t^*} \implies \frac{L^2}{\epsilon}=\num{2.49e-31}\frac{(L^*)^2}{t^*}$}
    \linebreak
    \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
TCU & = \frac{\text{purchasing cost} + \text{setup cost} + \text{holding cost}}{time} \\
    & = \frac{cy+K+h\frac{y}{2}t_0}{t_0}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, excuse me for my comment, but `mathtools` loads the `amsmath` package. Therefore you can delete `amsmath` .

Comment: @Sebastiano done!

Comment: `figure` shouldn't be put inside `center`. That could leave extra space *unassociated with `figure`* that might well change the placement of the figure, including moving it to a different page.

Comment: This still suffers from the problem that the `figure` environment is allowed to float elsewhere, which is what OP is trying to avoid.